# Parsing text data to JSON form using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm able to parse the text and convert to a JSON data also if the key and value are in a horizontal way but not getting to know how to convert if it's vertical can anyone help on this.

**Horizontal**

```
name test 
dob 23/07/1993
age 34
salary 18000

**Code**
for line in fh: 
    command, description = line.strip().split(None, 1) 
    dict1[command] = description.strip()
```

**vertical**

```
name dob age salary
test 23/07/1993 34 1800
test12 23/07/1933 34 7000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done with pandas data frame,hope this helps

```
import pandas as pd 
from io import StringIO 
StringData = StringIO("""name dob age salary
test 23/07/1993 34 1800
test12 23/07/1933 34 7000""") 
df = pd.read_csv(StringData, sep =" ") 
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

### EDIT - Updated Answer

I mistakenly confused the "horizontal" and "vertical" in my original answer. That will work for horizontal. For the vertical, you can utilize `pandas.DataFrame.read_csv` to read in your file, and then either `pandas.DataFrame.to_json` or `pandas.DataFrame.to_dict` to either output to a JSON file or load into a Python dictionary, respectively.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("vertical.txt", sep=" ")

# Write to a separate JSON file
df.to_json("vertical.json", orient="records")

# Load into a Python dictionary
vertical_dict = df.to_dict(orient="records")
```

### Previous Answer

In the horizontal format, your first column is your key, and your second is your value. With that assumption, you can do the following:

```
with open("sample.txt", "r") as infile:
    line = infile.readline()
    result = {}

    while line:
        tokens = line.split()
        key = tokens[0]
        value = tokens[1]
        result.update({key: value})
        line = infile.readline()

print(result)

# Output
{'dob': '23/07/1993', 'name': 'test', 'age': '34', 'salary': '18000'}
```

Comment: I'm not getting the result set same as urs @gallen

Comment: In what way? It's tough for me to provide further clarity if I don't know how your results differ.

Comment: {'name': 'dob', 'test': '23/07/1993'} this the output which we get when we run ur code

Comment: @ChirstyCR_007 I made a mistake between "vertical" and "horizontal" as the way the samples appear made them seem opposite in my head. I have updated my answer with a solution that will work properly for your vertical sample.